# btn ( Button) step showing error and Interstitial Ad not working

Tags: android-studio, admob, interstitial

I have tried to add btn (Button) setup. But it is giving error and crashing my app. please help.

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    btn = (Button)findViewById( R.id.image_button_download );

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
    });

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    // Create ad request
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    // Attempt loading ad for interstitial
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    // Create and set AdListener for interstitial
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        // Listen for when user closes ad
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // When user closes ad end this activity (go back to first activity)
            finish();
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Listen for when user presses button
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If a interstitial is ready, show it
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Logcat Error

```
2019-10-17 19:52:57.633 5045-5204/? E/IptablesRestoreController: [iptables debug]iptables-restore execute *filter
    -D fw_powersave -m owner --uid-owner 10161 -j RETURN
    COMMIT
2019-10-17 19:52:57.676 5045-5204/? E/IptablesRestoreController: [iptables debug]iptables-restore execute done *filter
    -D fw_powersave -m owner --uid-owner 10161 -j RETURN
    COMMIT
    , res : 0
2019-10-17 19:53:01.261 5045-5204/? E/IptablesRestoreController: [iptables debug]iptables-restore execute *filter
    -A fw_standby_uid -m owner --uid-owner 9510025 -j DROP
    COMMIT
2019-10-17 19:53:01.305 5045-5204/? E/IptablesRestoreController: [iptables debug]iptables-restore execute done *filter
    -A fw_standby_uid -m owner --uid-owner 9510025 -j DROP
    COMMIT
    , res : 0
```

Comment: post the stacktrace error from Logcat

Comment: Please check now i have uploaded Logcat error.